# при любом клике элемента передается одно и тоже значение

Tags: android, listview

Есть код, при клике на TextView, обрабатывается клик, и передается в другое активити, но на деле получается, что передается одно и тоже значение. никак не пойму почему?

```
public class AdapterListMelodies extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<Model_Melodies.Melodies> items;
private DisplayImageOptions options;
private Model_Melodies.Melodies modelMelodiesMelodies;
protected ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

public AdapterListMelodies(Context context, ArrayList<Model_Melodies.Melodies> items) {
    mContext = context;
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitems, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.nameArtist = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nameArtist);
        holder.nameSounds = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nameSounds);
        holder.cover = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }
    modelMelodiesMelodies = items.get(position);
    holder.nameArtist.setText(modelMelodiesMelodies.getArtist());
    holder.nameArtist.setOnClickListener(this);
    holder.nameSounds.setText(modelMelodiesMelodies.getTitle());
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(mContext));
    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_stub)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .build();
    imageLoader.displayImage(modelMelodiesMelodies.getPicUrl(), holder.cover, options);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.nameArtist) {
        Intent i = new Intent(mContext, Activity_Player.class);
        String imgUri = modelMelodiesMelodies.getPicUrl();
        String soundUri = modelMelodiesMelodies.getDemoUrl();
        i.putExtra(Activity_Player.EXTRA_IMAGE_URL, imgUri);
        i.putExtra(Activity_Player.EXTRA_SOUND_URL, soundUri);
        mContext.startActivity(i);
    }
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView cover;
    public TextView nameArtist;
    public TextView nameSounds;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас в адаптере есть поле `private Model_Melodies.Melodies modelMelodiesMelodies;` которое вы заполняете в методе `getView()`. При клике вы достаете значение из этого поля, отсюда и одинаковые значения.

Данное поле абсолютно не нужно. Вам надо переопределить метод `getItem(int position)` так, чтобы он возвращал элемент из коллекции по позиции, т.е выглядеть он должен так:

```
@Override
public Model_Melodies.Melodies getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}
```

Тогда везде где необходимо получить объект по позиции достаточно будет вызвать его.

Далее, т.к. у вас обработчик в адаптере, то он не знает позицию элемента по которому был произведен клик. Можно добавить во ViewHolder поле типа `int`, в котором будет хранится позиция к которому относится данная view. После чего в обработчике клика можно будет получить эту позицию и по ней объект из коллекции.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.nameArtist) {
        int position = ((ViewHolder)v.getTag()).position;
        Model_Melodies.Melodies item = getItem(int position);
        // остальная работа
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

мне кажется что вам нужно реализовать `OnItemClickListener` вместо `OnClickListener`